# Is it possible to use an image in the background of the log on screen?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, login, desktop-customization

I found a way to change the background colour but I couldn't find any way to use an image instead.

When you boot the computer you're presented with the lock screen before you go to the log on one, so you can choose a background image for the former easily but I couldn't find the equivalent setting for the later.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: There's only like a bazillion (probably) programs and utilities that will do this. Did you bother to Google?

Comment: @joeqwerty Do tell me one please, it's not the lock screen but the log on one (i.e. the one where you input your password).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm inclined to say that isn't an option as things stand right now. That colour is based on the primary colour chosen for your user profile, so it's not based on any image. Instead, it's just a simple colour fill. Perhaps the ability to change that may come in the future, but I don't think it's possible without some 3rd party modifications to Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm afraid it is not possible as of now.

Comment: Here is some developer info on the secure desktop and how to program for/around it.  http://calebdelnay.com/blog/2012/01/displaying-a-program-on-the-windows-secure-desktop

Answer (score 1):

There is a third-party plugin for Windows called [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) that will allow you to do this. This feature is not available in the free version but you can use the full version free for 30 days.

[image]

Comment: I just tried a trial version, but it doesn't seem to work on Windows 8(.1), maybe it's not even possible.

Comment: It looks like the trial (free) version doesn't support Logon Screen tweaking - http://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/

Comment: Just tested again, the trial version allows to use all of the functionality of the application; and it worked in a Windows 7 I have around but it didn't in Windows 8.1. Thanks for the heads up on that program, I like its ability to put extra buttons in windows (e.g. to keep it on top of others).

Comment: Yeah, that robot on the log-on screen and the nice blue background in the screenshot above said it all; it only works with Windows7. It won't work with Windows 8.x.